# What is a "Symbolication warning"?

Tags: macos, gcc, crash-reports

I've got a user reporting crashes in my Mac OS X application, and their console logs report the following:

```
Symbolication warning: error parsing FDE at 0x100052649 in:\n
```

Does anyone have any insight into what this might be? I assume that somehow the symbols have been stripped from my app in a way that gets in the way of Mac OS X's crash reporter, but I've not seen it before.

Answer (score 0):

I can honestly say that I have never seen this one before. I have seen a number of other dynamic linking problems just not this one. If the user is amenable to helping you with this defect, you might want to write a shell script to enable some dynamic linking environment variables and then launch your application.

```
#! /bin/bash
export DYLD_PRINT_LIBRARIES=1
export DYLD_PRINT_LIBRARIES_POST_LAUNCH=1
export DYLD_PRINT_APIS=1
export DYLD_PRINT_BINDINGS=1
export DYLD_PRINT_DOFS=1
open -a Console.app > /tmp/link-log 2>&1
```

The output log might provide some hint as to what is going on. You could also capture the output of `otool` and other command line utilities to check for unexpected libraries and what not.

You might want to [google Symbolication](http://www.google.com/search?q=Symbolication) to get a better handle of what is going on here. I came across an [interesting chunk of code from Darwin](http://www.google.com/search?q=Symbolication) that points this to a dynamic symbol lookup warning. There is also a utility called [Shark](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/SharkUserGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html) that may be of interest as well.

Good luck...

Comment: My best guess is that the user's install has something very wrong with it - I've only seen this from one user so far.

Answer (score 0):

I just found this topic via Google because I'm having the same problem. The StarCraft installer crashes immediately. It points to /usr/libexec/oah/translate, which seems to work perfectly well. My guess is this has something to do with the fact the computer it doesn't work on runs iDeneb 1.3 (aka Mac OS X 86 for use on non-Apple hardware), whereas the computer that can run the application just fine has a genuine version of Leopard.

Comment: That's Rosetta — the component that allows the user to run PowerPC apps on Intel macs. That would certainly explain a few things in both of our cases.